# suzanne the monkey is facing wrong direction

Tags: bezier-curves

this is a curve array of objects that follow a curve, but with an additional points created by the node "curve line".
I can't get the monkey head to follow the curve angle, I mean right now she is facing the same direction of the compass.
the objective is to make all the monkeys face the back of each other like people in a row in the real world. it is straight forward to make it with a single curve but the way I setup it has to be two curves running in paralell.
[image]
[image]